# Key Value option in package

Tags: hyperref, package-writing, key-value, package-options

I trying to write a package, and I'd like to specify whether there should be colour or not.
I'd like to do:

```
\usepackage[color=false]{foo}
```

and have this set

```
\RequirePackage[color=false]{hyperref}
```

or true as the case may be.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I would us two options : the default one would be bw for black and white, and the second one would be color.

Comment: My comment is a general one which doesn't take care of the package hyperref.

Comment: Duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12631/5763

Comment: I saw http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12631/5763, but I wanted to know how to expand out the text, which it didn't outline. However, I did reread the documentation for pgfopts, and used that to do what I wanted. I think the main issue with pgfopts was not understanding how pgfkeys worked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want all the options to your package to be passed to hyperref then you can just do

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{hyperref}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

see `clsguide.tex` documentation in the LaTeX base.

I just read clsguide:-) and if this is *all* you want to do, it points out that there is a more efficient shortcut to all the above three lines

```
\RequirePackageWithOptions{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `keyreader`

```
\begin{filecontents}{mypack.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypack}

\usepackage{keyreader}

% Define the keys in family MYFAM and set the
% macor prefix to my@
\krddefinekeys{MYFAM}[my@]{
    % define a command key 'say' that sores
    % it’s value in \my@say
    cmd/say/jump/;
    % [1] define a boolean 
    bool/colori/true/;
    % [2] define a boolean and store the value
    bool/colorii/true/\def\my@colorii{#1};
}
% booleand are not preset by defualt so we
% do it manually
\krdsetkeys{MYFAM}{colori=false,colorii=false}

% Process the package options
\krdProcessOptions<MYFAM>\relax

% with version [1]
%\ifmy@colori
%   \RequirePackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
%\else
%   \RequirePackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
%\fi

% with version [2]
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=\my@colorii]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{%
    % use the value of 'say'
    #1 says \my@say.
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
    say={sit down},
    colori=true,% [1]
    colorii=false,% [2]
]{mypack}

\begin{document}
\mycmd{Simon}

\url{www.myurl.com}
\end{document}
```

**Notes**

- `hyperref` has no `color` option (at least my version hasn’t)
- Version [1] is the shorter was if you want to access only one `hyperref` key
- Version [2] is better if you want to access more then one option.

  - For that we store the value of the option an pass it to `hyperref` later.
    Booleans don’t store their value by default, they only create new `\if…`
  - Why not use a `cmd` for this version? Because `bool` key checks if it’t value
    matches true or false

---

Maybe it’s better to use the pdf key processing since it’s more related with the `beamer` class, but I’m not familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `kvoptions` and `etoolbox`, in your `.sty` file, write:

```latex
...
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

%% if the variable 'color' is
%% 1. not included                  : it will be set to 'false'
%% 2. included but not given a value: it will be set to 'true'
%% 3. included and given a value    : it will be set to the value that is given
\DeclareStringOption[false]{color}[true]

\newif \ifcolor %% new Boolean variable is default to 'false'
\ifdefstring{\foo@color}{true}{\colortrue}{} %% set the Boolean variable to 'true' if '\foo@color' is 'true'

\ifcolor
\RequirePackage[color = true]{hyperref}
\else
\RequirePackage[color = false]{hyperref}
\fi
...
```

Then in your document you can specify the option 'color' with:

```latex
...
\usepackage[color]{foo}         %% color = true
\usepackage[color = true]{foo}  %% color = true
\usepackage[color = false]{foo} %% color = false
...
```